# Installing Lubuntu without changing partitions

Tags: installation, lubuntu

I've just downloaded and burned Lubuntu to a disc, and want to install it. However during the installation it wants to split my HD up in 2 partitions. I really dont want this, as i'm afraid my current Win7 installation will get corrupt, and just want to keep 1 partition in general.

Can i somehow skip this step, if not why?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, i used to have Ubuntu installed which didnt prompt me with the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you installed Ubuntu using wubi.

My advice is to suggest you install lubuntu onto ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

If you do not want to do that, my next piece of advice would be to go ahead and do a standard installation.

Resize your windows partitions from within windows, make some free space, and install lubuntu into the resulting free space.

Comment: It just seems kinda scary. But thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It is a big step to start partitioning your hard drive. Be sure to read the documentation, back up your data, and ask for help. The vast majority of the time resizing goes without any problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help! I indeed just made a backup and split my drive up. (Posted from my fresh Lubuntu install)

Answer (score 0):

A separate partition will have to be added if you want to install alongside another OS.

You can however install Ubuntu with Wubi within Windows7 for information and installation instructions and downloads look [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)